# How to get pairs by a column in spark dataframe like python pandas?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Hello~ I'm a rookie in spark. I want to get pairs with a column in dataframe, every item in col("all_mv_id") get others to make up pairs like this:

Before:

```
+---------+
|all_mv_id|
+---------+
|      131|
|      121|
|     2223|
|   123412|
|     3982|
+---------+
```

after:

```
+------+------+
|  id_1|  id_2|
+------+------+
|   131|   121|
|   131|  2223|
|   131|123412|
|   131|  3982|
|   131| 54281|
|   121|  2223|
|   121|123412|
|   121|  3982|
|   121| 54281|
|  2223|123412|
|  2223|  3982|
|  2223| 54281|
|123412|  3982|
|123412| 54281|
|  3982| 54281|
+------+------+
```

I mean, in python pandas, I will do like this:

```
# generate data
ids = [('all_mv_id', ['131', '121', '2223', '123412', '3982', '54281'])]
df = pd.DataFrame.from_items(ids)

all_mv_id = list(df.all_mv_id)
temp_container = []
for i in range(len(all_mv_id)):
    for j in range(i+1,len(all_mv_id)):
        temp_container.append([all_mv_id[i],all_mv_id[j]])

df_1 = pd.DataFrame(temp_container)
df_1.columns = ["id_1", "id_2"]
```

But how to translate this which python in pandas to scala in spark dataframe?
I tried `ListBuffer`, but it seems that it can't be appended tuples into it.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that regular **self join** with the condition `left.id < right.id` should do the job:

```scala
val df = List("131", "121", "2223", "123412", "3982").toDF("id")

df.as("left")
    .join(df.as("right"), $"left.id" < $"right.id")
    .select($"left.id" as "id_1", $"right.id" as "id_2")
    .show
```

Result:

```
+------+------+
|  id_1|  id_2|
+------+------+
|   131|  2223|
|   131|  3982|
|   131| 54281|
|   121|   131|
|   121|  2223|
|   121|123412|
|   121|  3982|
|   121| 54281|
|  2223|  3982|
|  2223| 54281|
|123412|   131|
|123412|  2223|
|123412|  3982|
|123412| 54281|
|  3982| 54281|
+------+------+
```

Comment: Thank U very much~~ I got it~ Thanks~

Comment: @konverse If you found this anwser helpful, you can accept it :)

Comment: I'm sorry~ I tried it~ But the system showed "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score." o(╥﹏╥)o

Comment: @konverse Below upvote button, there's tick button to accept the answer. If you accept it you'll also get two reputation points :)